# Differential Geometry and Origami

Tags: differential-geometry

Would anyone know how to relate origami with differential geometry? I mean clearly you can see how geometry plays into it but how would you describe it in terms of differential

Comment: I actually do not think that origami are so smooth...

Comment: From an analysts perspective: Fold implies non-differentiability. Any origami is differentiable almost everywhere (except for set of Hausdorff measure 1). Depending how good at origami you are, an origami is an example of a piecewise affine surface. There is a definition of a Lipschitz manifold, that may be more suitable for these objects.

Comment: I suppose that one might consider a specific origami construction, and consider its deformation space, by varying the angles of the folds and the lengths of the folds so that the result is combinatorially the same. Maybe this deformation space might be amenable to a differential geometric analysis.

Comment: So considering that we're talking about paperfolding you would describe it as being differentiable almost everywhere? I mean I know that through folding you create creases and lines and curvatures but I'm still not sure how one could say it that it describes the relation

Comment: Would saying Algorithms based on differential geometry quantify all geometric aspects of the surfaces. Curvature clasification defines the shape and orientation of points on the folded surface. The curvature threshold introduces methods to extract significant aspects of fold shapes by disregarding curvature magnitudes less than a certain value. This permits the evaluation of the cylindricity of the folded surface at particular points.